# Url.Action Assumes Additional RouteValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial page containing the following javascript:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Users", null)/' + userID;
```

This works fine on every page, except for pages with the url structure:

```
/Site/Users/Details/{ID}
```

For example when ID = 25, asp.net will output:

```
var url = '/Site/Users/Details/25/' + userID;
```

But it should be:

```
var url = '/Site/Users/Details/' + userID;
```

How can I prevent `@Url.Action` from assuming this additional route value?

**Edit:**

My route contains the default route configuration...

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: What does your Route look like?

Comment: id is an optional parameter in my controller `Users`: `public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)`

Comment: I meant your RegisterRoutes function (usually in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs)

Comment: I updated the question. It contains the default configuration.

Comment: Yes, userID is javascript. The line `var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Users", null)/' + userID;` is javascript as mentioned in the question (obviously the @Url.Action part is compiled server side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new { id = -1})'; //Render Url with -1 value
url = url.replace(-1, userID); //replace -1 with userId
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the id in route values for the Url Action method?

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new {id = userID})';
```

Comment: Because, if I understood correctly, `userID` is defined in javascript.

Comment: In that case try changing the parameter from id to userId and have the url action like `var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Users", null)?userID=' + userID;`

Comment: @JamesSantiago I'd have to change the route value from `/Site/Users/Details/25` to `/Site/Users/Details/?userID=25` in order to do that. Just doesn't look as good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
var urlString = Url.Action("Details", "Users", null, "http");
var uri = new Uri(urlString);
```

and in javascript:

```
var url = '@uri.AbsolutePath' + '/' + userID;
```